# How to setup other wifi radios than ax on RT-AX56U

Tags: router, wireless-router

Anyone knows how to change settings for other radios than the ax one in Asus RT-AX56U router?

It seems that the settings (even the advanced ones) have no selector for which radio they apply to, there are separate settings for 2.4Ghz and for 5Ghz, but security tab is shared.
I guess I missed something, or maybe I need to enable advanced settings somewhere (on top of "advanced" tab)

My use case is following:
I want to setup n/ax radio with WPA2 encryption,
but b with WEP encryption
I also want to disable g and ac radios.

The reason for that is that my network printer only supports b/g and only with WEP.
And the reason for disabling every second standard is simply to avoid unnecessary interferences (since they work on the same frequencies).

Answer (score 1):

There is only one "radio" in your router `b`, `g`, `n`, and `ax` are simply different modes the radio can operate in and newer modes will be faster. You cannot simply "disable radios" to use older modes.

Having devices connected using older modes will generally force other devices to fall down to that mode as well. You will be completely limiting your network speed to the maximum supported by the slowest device. Disabling standards will be useless because you will only be preventing devices from moving up standards, and thus potentially using higher speeds, rather than preventing interference.

You might be able to revert back to `b` or `g`, but WEP is [considered completely broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Weak_security) and you would be leaving your network completely open to almost anyone by using it. Essentially anyone could browse machines on your network and use your internet connection.

You would really be better off replacing the printer, or if it has ethernet then using either an Ethernet to wireless access point or just plain ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for that is that my network printer only supports b/g and
> only with WEP.

I suggest you not use the printer this way as your network may be compromised.

Get a small Print Server (HP and others) and hook your printer to the network with Ethernet. This will work and be secure.

The other expert suggested replacing the printer and it may be worthwhile to do that.